# Bash regular expression groups not working

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to pattern match in my bash script but for some reason the BASH_REMATCH var is not being set with my groups.

Code below:

```
if [[ "SYSENV01" =~ ^(SYS)(ENV)(01)$ ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}        
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

Weirdly this prints out SYSENV01 then 2 empty lines to the command line - so it must be matching; however, the groups do not appear.

Any ideas? This has had me in circles for ages.

Comment: what version of bash are you using? That code works just fine in bash 4.2.45

Comment: Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (ia64-hp-hpux11.31)

Comment: Make sure that you are using bash (executable with `#!/bin/bash`) or run it with `bash filename`.  Otherwise it could be using another interpreter (this won't work with `zsh` or `dash`)

Comment: Yep - got that at the top of my file and when I try from bash shell it still doesn't work .i.e. [[ "SYSENV01" =~ ^(SYS)(ENV)(01)$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} - however BASH_REMATCH[0] works

Comment: @user2294382 are you sure you're using bash?  What does `echo $SHELL` say?

Comment: Interesting.... echo $SHELL says /bin/ksh. I load the bash shell using bash. I have to admit I am pretty new to this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ExplosionPills echo $0 returns "bash" and the $BASH parameter is set to /usr/local/bin/bash which is what I have referenced at the top of my script.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters... it's probably a local shell issue.  Here's what I get locally:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "SYSENV01" =~ ^(SYS)(ENV)(01)$ ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}        
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

Outputs:

```
~/tmp › sh ./test.sh
SYSENV01
SYS
ENV
```

Bash version info:

```
~/tmp › bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Not as efficient, but here's the same thing using `cut`:

```
FIRST=$(echo "SYSENV01"  | cut -c1-3 )
SECOND=$(echo "SYSENV01" | cut -c4-6 )
THIRD=$(echo "SYSENV01"  | cut -c7- )

echo $FIRST
echo $SECOND
echo $THIRD
```

Maybe you can use something like that instead?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. Bash isn't my default shell, ksh is but I enter bash once I have logged into the server. My script references the bash executable at the top #!/usr/local/bin/bash. However, the script output is not the same for me! Can't figure this one out.

Comment: you're using HP-UX, which is notorious for being non-standard (I was an HP-UX Admin for many years).  Can you use other tools, such as `cut` to parse?